# Parse : make query finsih task before moving to the next task

Tags: android, parse-platform, progress

this is the main.
the buttons-

```
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.show();

                        getTheMarkerId();



                        markerisfalseortrue(0);


                        dialog.hide();

                        cdd.dismiss();
                    }
                });
```

this is the first task:
getTheMarkerId()

```
    queryfindmarkerid.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, ParseException e) {

            for (int i = 0; i<parseObjects.size(); i++)
            {
                if (parseObjects.get(i).getInt("longit") == themarkerlongitude && parseObjects.get(i).getInt("latit") ==  themarkerlatitude)
                {
                    themarkerid = parseObjects.get(i).getObjectId();
                }
            }


        }
    });
```

this is the second task- 
markerisfalseortrue(int i)

```
    if (i == 0)
    {
        queryfindmarkerid.getInBackground( themarkerid, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(ParseObject gameScore, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {

                    nowscore = gameScore.getInt("false");
                    gameScore.put("false", nowscore +1 );
                    gameScore.saveInBackground();



                }
            }
        });
```

The problem is: 
This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done.
How could I wait until the firse task is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the method call `markerisfalseortrue(0);` inside of the done method of the getTheMarkerId() method.  That way, the markerisfalseortrue() method won't run until the first network call has completed.

That is a common pattern to remember using the Parse querying methods with their callbacks - if you need to make a second request, or perform some action that can only be completed after the first network call has completed, activate that action in the done method of the first network call.